# How to get the sum of a dynamic column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to find the sum of all the entries in a column but i will keep adding the rows in that column. I need the total to come in a separate cell in a different column. Can anyone suggest a way.

Comment: can't you just say =sum( and then select the whole row? If you want static values use a $ e.x $B3 here the B is static but the 3 can changed based upon where the formula is. $B$3 here the full cell is static.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your columns are  [A1-An] then sum of the numbers is

```
= SUM(A1:An)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `=Sum(A:A)`
A is the column you want to Add
But don't write anything not needed in the Sum or the Result of the Sum, just write the number you need to add only.